# Overflow in div

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I am using asp.net . I am trying to fix the height of the div. I am hiding all the data in overflow. here is my code sample:

```
    <div id="Content" style="height: 90px !important; overflow: hidden; text-decoration: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; display: block; white-space: nowrap;">
    abcd<br />
    efgh<br />
    ijkl<br />
    mnop<br />
    qrst<br />
    uvwx<br />
</div>
```

I want to show the content upto ijkl and i want to show `More...` in over flow section here is a demo:

```
 abcd
 efgh
 ijkl
 more..
```

But I am Not been able to get this output. I want to give inline css. Please help me.

With Regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add label below the div, something like this:

```
<div id="Content" style="height: 90px !important; overflow: hidden; text-decoration: none">
    abcd<br />
    efgh<br />
    ijkl<br />
    mnop<br />
    qrst<br />
    uvwx
</div>
<label style="display: none">more..</label>
```

And play with its visibility with jquery when the text is overflown like this:

```
$(function(){
    if($('#Content')[0].scrollHeight > $('#Content').height())
        $('#overflowLabel').show();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25F23/)

Answer (score 0):

IS this what you want

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jMp5y/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="Content" style="height: 60px !important; overflow: hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis; text-decoration: none;
    display: block; white-space: nowrap;">
    abcd<br />
    efgh<br />
    ijkl<br />
    mnop<br />
    qrst<br />
    uvwx<br />
</div>
```

Comment: I think OP wants the text "more..." to be displayed if it overflows.

Comment: sir, I am able to hide the the overflow section but i want `more..` to be displayed in the next line

Comment: Sir, I have learnt in my past days that Nothing is Impossible. we just need to split this word by making it Im Possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through (JQuery API). 
Please go through this link [here](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl) and make it possible.